# referenced variable different after cout hex

Tags: c++

I dont know how to ask but i try my best; 

Simply

```
int a = 19;
int& b=a;
cout<<b<<endl;    //Output : 19
```

but now output is different after cout with hex

```
int a = 19;
int& b=a;
cout<<hex<<&a<<endl;     //0031F788
cout<<b<<endl;        //Output : 13
```

So why last output is 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the stream base was set to hexadecimal, and never back to decimal.

```
cout<<hex<<&a<<dec<<endl; // back to dec immediately, as it's done usually.
```

Comment: aha! becouse it SET to hex and never turn back decimal? right?

Comment: Yes that's what we've both just said

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ohh why is that? it looks like a bug, realy wonder why it has to be set if i dont put dec after.

Comment: @MustafaEkici you seem to believe that `hex` somehow modifies the "next" object, while in reality it affects the stream behavior. It's documented and expected, so not a bug (not a bug in the library implementation, at least).

Comment: It's not a bug. Normally if you want to output things in hex you probably have a few values to output, so it's easier if you don't have to keep setting hex each time. It's simply a design decision that was made. What is the problem with streaming `dec`?

Answer (score 5):

Because `19` is `0x13`, and you told the stream to output numbers in hexadecimal.

`hex` is "sticky", meaning it remains in effect on the stream object until you say otherwise, so you should stream `dec` when you're done with it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int  a = 19;
   int& b = a;

   cout << hex << &a << dec << endl;
   cout << b << endl;
}
```